# From PNG to BitmapImage. Transparency issue.

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've got some issue. 
I'm trying to load png-image from resources to BitmapImage propery in my viewModel like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = Resource1.ResourceManager.GetObject(String.Format("_{0}",i)) as Bitmap;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
BitmapImage bImg = new BitmapImage();

bImg.BeginInit();
bImg.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
bImg.EndInit();

this.Image = bImg;
```

But when I do it, I lose the transparency of the image.
So the question is how can I load png image from resources without loss of transparency?
Thanks,
Pavel.

Comment: @Felice Pollano: you should restore your deleted answer, which was good. Saving the image as a .bmp file and loading it will obviously lose the transparency.

Answer (score 8):

Ria's answer helped me resolve the transparency problem. Here's the code that works for me:

```
public BitmapImage ToBitmapImage(Bitmap bitmap)
{
  using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png); // Was .Bmp, but this did not show a transparent background.

    stream.Position = 0;
    BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage();
    result.BeginInit();
    // According to MSDN, "The default OnDemand cache option retains access to the stream until the image is needed."
    // Force the bitmap to load right now so we can dispose the stream.
    result.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    result.StreamSource = stream;
    result.EndInit();
    result.Freeze();
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because the `BMP` file format doesn't support transparency while the `PNG` file format does. If you want transparency you are going to have to use `PNG`.

Try [`ImageFormat.Png`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.png.aspx) for saving.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by 64-bit depth PNG images, which `BitmapImage` doesn't support. Photoshop seems to incorrectly display these as 16-bit, so you need to check with Windows Explorer:

- Right click the file.
- Click Properties.
- Go to the Details tab.
- Look for "Bit depth" - it's usually in the Image section, with width and height.

If it says 64, you need to re-encode the image with 16-bit depth. I suggest using [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/), since it properly handles PNG bit depths.

Answer (score 0):

I viewed this post to find answers to the same transparancy problem as here.

But then I saw the sample code given, and just wanted to share this code to load Image from Resources.

```
Image connection = Resources.connection;
```

Using this I found that I need not recode my images to 16 bit. Thanks.